# How do I follow two twitter accounts on Windows 10 mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, twitter

How do I follow two twitter accounts on Windows 10 mobile? I can configure only one on the Twitter App.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add multiple accounts to the official Twitter app.

Go to your profile and press the Two-Heads-Icon. There you can add an account, create a new one or sign out.

[image: Twitter for Windows 10 Mobile Screenshot]

Comment: I have no two heads icon in my official twitter app...

Comment: I added a screenshot of what it looks like for me (sorry for the German UI)

Answer (score 1):

You could use official [Twitter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/twitter/9wzdncrfj140) app along with other client apps. There are many available on store as free as well as paid services.

Some of the free twitter clients are [MeTweets](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/metweets/9nblggh08spl), [Peregrine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/peregrine/9wzdncrdmd2t), [Raven](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/raven-for-twitter/9nblggh5lhwv), etc.

Some o the paid twitter clients are [Fenice](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/fenice-for-twitter/9nblggh2plfg), [Tweetium](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/tweetium/9wzdncrdglpv), [Aeries](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/aeries/9nblggh0mbmg), [Aristea](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/aristea/9wzdncrdf4kf), [Twittone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/twittone/9nblggh1dnws), [Tweet it !](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/tweet-it-for-windows/9nblggh62lkc), etc.

Acc. to some surveys, Tweetium is considered 2nd best Twitter app on Store.

Comment: Tweetium offers support for signing in with up to 7 accounts as part of their paid Tweetium Pro subscription. Other Twitter clients may have something similar.

Comment: 7 accounts??? thats pretty good.